# Resolving absolute path from relative path

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, go, web-crawler, relative-path

I'm making a web-crawler and I'm trying to figure out a way to find out absolute path from relative path. 
I took 2 test sites. One in ROR and 1 made using Pyro CMS.

In the latter one, I found href tags with link "index.php". So, If I'm currently crawling at `http://example.com/xyz`, then my crawler will append and make it `http://example.com/xyz/index.php`. But the problem is that, I should be appending to root instead i.e. it should have been `http://example.com/index.php`. So if I crawl `http://example.com/xyz/index.php`, I'll find another "index.php" which gets appended again.

While in ROR, if the relative path starts with '/', I could've easily known that it is a root site.

I can handle the case of index.php, but there might be so many rules that I need to take care of if I start doing it manually. I'm sure there's an easier way to get this done.

Comment: Not as trivial task a task as you would assume. Feel free to draw inspiration from [here](https://github.com/cgray/geronimo/blob/master/src/Geronimo/UrlResolver.php).

Comment: Use `(*URL).Parse` (see http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Parse) which does exactly what you want (if these are actual, semantically correct, proper links no CMS custom nonsense).

Answer (score 1):

In Go, package [`path`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/) is your friend.

You can get the directory or folder from a path with [`path.Dir()`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/#Dir), e.g.

```
p := "/xyz/index.php"
dir := path.Dir(p)
fmt.Println("dir:", dir) // Output: "/xyz"
```

If you find a link with root path (starts with a slash), you can use that as-is.

If it is relative, you can join it with the `dir` above using [`path.Join()`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join). `Join()` will also "clean" the url:

```
p2 := path.Join(dir, "index.php")
fmt.Println("p2:", p2)
p3 := path.Join(dir, "./index.php")
fmt.Println("p3:", p3)
p4 := path.Join(dir, "../index.php")
fmt.Println("p4:", p4)
```

Output:

```
p2: /xyz/index.php
p3: /xyz/index.php
p4: /index.php
```

The "cleaning" tasks performed by `path.Join()` are done by [`path.Clean()`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/#Clean) which you can manually call on any path of course. They are:

> 1. Replace multiple slashes with a single slash.
> 2. Eliminate each `.` path name element (the current directory).
> 3. Eliminate each inner `..` path name element (the parent directory) along with the non-`..` element that precedes it.
> 4. Eliminate `..` elements that begin a rooted path: that is, replace `"/.."` by `"/"` at the beginning of a path.

And if you have a "full" url (with schema, host, etc.), you can use the [`url.Parse()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) function to obtain a [`url.URL`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) value from the raw url string which tokenizes the url for you, so you can get the path like this:

```
uraw := "http://example.com/xyz/index.php"
u, err := url.Parse(uraw)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Invalid url:", err)
}
fmt.Println("Path:", u.Path)
```

Output:

```
Path: /xyz/index.php
```

Try all the examples on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Va_GFMhJs9).