# How can I resolve a relative path to absolute path in golang?

Tags: go, io, path

Is there a api like 'path.resolve' in node? Or something can do the same?

For Example (nodejs code):
`path.resolve("~/sample.sh")`
Should got: `/home/currentuser/sample.sh`

Comment: This technically isn't relative to absolute, it's tilde expansion. `~/sample.sh` is an absolute path (what it refers to does not change based on CWD). The tilde is just a shortcut for the user's (absolute) home directory path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand tilde to home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609732/expand-tilde-to-home-directory)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Resolving `~` (denoting the user home) is a different story, and usually it's the shell that resolves this. For details see [Expand tilde to home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609732/expand-tilde-to-home-directory).

If you want to do it from Go code, you may use the [`user.Current()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#Current) function to get details about the current user, including its home folder which will be `User.HomeDir`. But still, you'll have to handle replacing this yourself.

Original answer follows.

---

You may use [`path.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join) or [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join).

For example:

```
base := "/home/bob"
fmt.Println(path.Join(base, "work/go", "src/github.com"))
```

Output:

```
/home/bob/work/go/src/github.com
```

You may use [`path.Clean()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Clean) and [`filepath.Clean()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Clean) to "remove" dots `.` and double dots `..` from  your path.

You may use [`filepath.Abs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to resolve relative paths and get an absolute (prepending the working directory if it's not absolute). `filepath.Abs()` also calls `Clean()` on the result.

For example:

```
fmt.Println(filepath.Abs("/home/bob/../alice"))
```

Outputs:

```
/home/alice <nil>
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Yu-ilGiJpT).

See related question: [Resolving absolute path from relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620870/resolving-absolute-path-from-relative-path/32623803#32623803)

Comment: This seems like a red herring - `Join` doesn't have anything to do with the question that was asked, nor does `Clean`.  It's not until the last 3 paragraphs or that the question is addressed.

Comment: @Adrian The first version of the question didn't mention resolving `~`, just resolving paths. But yes, they are not relevant anymore.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, didn't see that it had been edited.

Comment: @Adrian Edited the answer to make it obvious.