# Setting a user defined file in go with bufio

Tags: go, filepath

I'm trying to open a csv in go from a user defined filepath (in this case just an entry in the command line).

I've been using the bufio package and taking in a user string, and then using filepath.abs to try to convert it to a proper filepath.

```
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("What file do you want to enter?")
    filePath, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    filePath, _ = filepath.Abs(filePath)
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(file.Name(), "opened successfully")
```

Unfortunately this just returns a "no such file or directory" error even though the file exists in the working directory. Is there some quirk in go with how strings are handled that would be keeping this from working?

Comment: `ReadString` returns a string including the delimiter, so `filePath` has a newline at the end.

Comment: i think this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261719/how-can-i-resolve-a-relative-path-to-absolute-path-in-golang , or you if you can print the path and share here so could find if something wrong with path

Comment: Aha @AndySchweig that was what was causing it thank you!